# How to run new added binaries using makefile

Tags: command-line, gcc, make

I have added some pre-compiled tools for developing ARM into the `/home/charlie/bin/ARM` directory. When I modify the path by `PATH=/home/charlie/bin/ARM:"$PATH"` I can execute `arm-none-eabi-gcc` in the terminal.

However when I run `make` I got this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: arm-none-eabi-gcc: not found.
```

What is the proper mechanism to make new programs located anywhere to be executed like native binaries (for example `gcc`) and why was I able to run it in terminal after changing PATH but `make` had problems ?

Comment: Did you `export` the modified PATH variable? Did you just modify it in the current terminal, or add it to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile and re-`source` it?

Comment: I added it to ~/.bashrc and then I re- `source` -ed it.

Comment: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: How should I do that? Should I just type answer below or should I also mark it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

OP's original answer:

The PATH needs to be EXPORTed too!

```
export PATH=/home/charlie/bin/ARM:"$PATH"
```